# How to generalise autofilter field value

Tags: excel, vba

I am facing problem in running the below line in my macro coding as the field 20 is not constant. I can find the exact column to which filter needs to be applied. But how to generalise that value in the coding.

Selection.AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:=">=3", _ Operator:=xlAnd

Answer (score 0):

Say we have data like:

[image]

and we want to filter on **size**, but don't know which column to pick.  We just look along the first row to find **size**:

```
Sub omer()
  Dim r As Range, i As Long
  critt = "size"
  i = 1

  For Each r In Selection.Rows(1).Cells
    If r.Value = critt Then
      crittcol = i
    End If
    i = i + 1
  Next r

  MsgBox crittcol

  Selection.AutoFilter Field:=crittcol, Criteria1:=">=3", Operator:=xlAnd

End Sub
```

which yields:

[image]